# get the methods return value within the method

Tags: c#

I know that I can simply use a variable but out of sheer curiosity is there a way to get the return value of a method within that method.

```
public bool MyTest()
{
    try
    {
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myresult == true)
           dosomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with a variable?

Comment: If my fading memory serves, in VB the return value could be set and read by using the name of the containing method. There is no such syntax in C# so far as I know.

Comment: why the downgrades? It is out of curiosity. It must be stored "somewhere". Just wondering if one has access to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no C# syntax built-in for that.